# using ng-bind to define transcluded content on a directive that uses transclusion

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, ng-bind, angularjs-ng-transclude

Consider `some-directive` with the following definition object:

```
{
   restrict: "E",
   transclude: true,
   template: "<div>content: <div ng-transclude></div></div>"
}
```

I can use it this way:

```
<some-directive>{{someContent}}</some-directive>
```

and not surprisingly, `someContent` will be placed where it has to.

But I want to be able to use it this way also:

```
<some-directive ng-bind='someContent'></some-directive>
```

**Here is an [example of the problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/A36MqpFsgEIZBHdO68r0?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me *why* you must use `ng-bind` over `{{ }}`, but if you must, then one way to solve this is to transclude the entire element using `transclude: "element"`.

This, however, ignores the `template` property, so you'd need to manually add it in the `compile` function. And, you'd need to make the priority of your directive higher than that of `ngBind` (which has the default priority `1`):

```
return{
  restrict: "E",
  transclude: "element",
  priority: 10,
  compile: function(tElem, tAttrs){
    var template = "\
      <div class='some-directive'>\
        <div class='some-directive-header'>My custom component</div>\
        <div class='some-directive-body' ng-transclude></div>\
      </div>";

    tElem.replaceWith(template);
  }
};
```

[Your forked plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6FIbP3zlz15I6j4K5eDl?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

This fixes your example:

```
<some-directive ><span ng-bind='someContent' /></some-directive>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qwKFYv1WAbpPTR1gGuqA?p=preview